# Can't access object property that's been set through an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, this, object-literal

Ok, I'm really at a loss here, and totally can't figure it out.

I have an object literal

say:..

In my object literal,

I call the function, get comments, a property of the object. 
it turns an AJAX call on and in the AJAX success method, 
I save the data , to `self.commentsData`

I have used

```
var self = this;
```

before the AJAX and therefore SELF refers to the object and not the AJAX.

But I cannot access this property from anywhere else.

I logged self to console, both from inside the AJAX and outside the AJAX and from another function in the object literal (the AJAX is also part of a function in the object literal) 
and the weirdest thing shows:
inside the AJAX I see my object `Class { with all the properties }`
Outside the AJAX I see the object without the `commentsData` property,
**However, if I click on it, the `commentsData` property does show in the drop down menu, just like it does in the other self log. Using `self.commentsData` however doesn't seem to work from anywhere in the object except for inside the ajax success method.**

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. This almost looks like a bug in javascript, or the chrome console. Has anyone ever seen this before ?

I would post my code but it's fairly long and contains many other functions and would be a tad tedious to look through.

Comment: Your ajax call is **asynchronous**. The "inside" part you talk about is the code that the browser calls when the operation is complete. The overall ajax call however returns immediately.

Comment: Post the full code, that way you won't have to write so much to explain what it does :)

Comment: Voting to close, as no code is available.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) and [console.log() async or sync?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572)